Attic access door replacement key
I am looking for a way to access this door, but do not have a key. Our builder did not include it with the home, and I was able to get a picture of our neighbor’s key. I would like to find somewhere to purchase a replacement, but do not know what to ask for. I tried looking for “utility panel with T-handle lock” but a lot of the results are more access panels and this is a door to my attic. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!



Contact the builder would be my first step.

Does your neighbors key open the lock?

Yes, the key pictured is the neighbors key and opens the door. I figured that it was a standard door used for attic access, but if not then yeah contacting the builder might be the only option.

Take the key to a locksmith or even try carving one out of wood.

"Carving one from wood" is a great way to jam the lock with bits of broken wood.
